# Japerreports Error: Parameter 'DATABASE_TIMEZONE' does not exist'

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, subreport

I have a jasper report which works fine in iReports. When I run the same report on Jasperserver it gives me an error message 'Parameter "DATABASE_TIMEZONE does not exist"'. My main report has multiple subreports and the subreports further have multiple subreports referenced. I have close to 30 subreports. Here is the error log from jasperserver:

```
    2016-10-04 19:46:58,519 ERROR ManagementServiceImpl,https-openssl-nio-192.0.0.0-443-exec-24:1332 - caught Throwable exception: Parameter "DATABASE_TIMEZONE" does not exist.
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Parameter "DATABASE_TIMEZONE" does not exist.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRAbstractQueryExecuter.getValueParameter(JRAbstractQueryExecuter.java:869)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRAbstractQueryExecuter.getValueParameter(JRAbstractQueryExecuter.java:887)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.getValueParameter(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.java:149)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.<init>(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.java:133)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuterFactory.createQueryExecuter(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuterFactory.java:51)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1126)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:696)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.setParameters(BaseReportFiller.java:437)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:548)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:396)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:732)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:221)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I think some of your subreport expressions is wrong. Maybe you didnot pass this parameter from main report to subreport

Comment: @AlexK- I created the parameter "DATABASE_TIMEZONE" in all my subreports but still keep getting the same error message. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: At least one of your subreport's expression (*subreportExpression*) is wrong (at main report or at "parent" subreport). There is a difference in expression when you are using the JR Server or just JasperReports client (GUI or some code). Check details at [documentation section](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jasper-reports/5452/using-subreports#t=20161004211537636147&a=parameters)

Comment: Are you using this property? `<parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>`

Comment: @AlexK- I'm using below property in my master report. <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "JobTicket_5_jobDetSec_SR.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>

Comment: What version of JRS?

Comment: Did you check the topic of documentation?

Comment: JRS version is 6.3.0 and ireports version is 5.6.0

Comment: Yes, I did check the documentation. The jasperserver expression should look like "repo:subreport.jrxml". I have a lot of subreports referenced to the main report.

Comment: Show as much Java code as allowed.